# Numerically solving Navier-Stokes-Darcy (Brinkman) equation

Tags: fluid-dynamics, resource-recommendations, computational-physics, porous-media, transport-phenomena

I'm trying to learn fluid dynamics in porous media and I need to solve Navier-Stokes-Darcy (Brinkman) equation numerically but I'm not sure how to do that (I was trying to use method of lines for discretization in space domain and ode15s (a MATLAB built-in ODE solver) to solve remaining ODE) but I have difficulties in that.

I took a look at some articles solving flow in porous media numericaly but they didn't explain the numerical part fully and had no code within.

Can anyone please suggest a source for numerical implementation of Brinkman equation in porous media?

(If it contains  some codes and the codes are in Matlab it is so much better)

Edit:
Description of the problem I'm dealing with:
Generally it's a system of 3 coupled time dependent PDEs including:

Brinkman equation (flow inside porous media with time dependent porosity) the gravity effect is neglected, reaction-deffusion equation (transport and consumption of a solute), an equation containing cell deffusion and cell growth term.
The computational domain is 2D.

More detailed description of problem:

The physical domain is a porous cylinder and at the inlet the velocity has just an axial component (and it is a function of radial distance.

I assumed that :the porosity distribution is homogeneous inside domain and pressure drop occurs just in axial direction, the problem has rotational symmetry.
so I choosed axial (vertical) cross section of the cylinder as computational domain.(so the equations should be solved in a 2D domain.)

B.C and I.C of flow:

I have vlocity of flow at inlet of porous media. and at the outlet the pressure is set to zero, and at t=0 (intial condition)
Thre is no fluid in the domain so the "p" pressure matrix is zero.

My problem is not challenging at all but I couldn't solve it.

Main problem

As I know now my main problem in numerically
implementing Brinkman equation is that i don't know how to calculate/update pressure in each time step (I did not relate the pressure to any other variable so it seems what I get for pressure drop when i use differencing formulaes is 0-0=0 in each node every time step.
'and i know it's wrong' but i don't know who should i include pressure drop term ? Cause i'm solving for velocity I guess I should relate it to velocity but i don't know how).

Comment: Please provide some details of the problem you're dealing with: reference to Brinkman eqaution, physical process you're trying to model (so we can see if its a monodimensional or multi-dimensional problem), domain and boundary conditions (or we can choose them from your description of the problem)

Comment: Well for pretty much any CFD system, your choices are [finite element method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_element_method) or [finite volume method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_volume_method). Pick one & run with it. Though writing a full CFD suite from scratch (especially wanting something as slow as Matlab) is going to be fairly time consuming, so you might want to just see what existing C/C++/Fortran CFD codes exist already and see how you can modify those to account for porous materials.